# Is a bijective morphism between metric spaces necessarily an isomorphism

Tags: metric-spaces

Does the inverse morphism for a bijective isometry necessarily preserve the metric or should the preservation of the metric for the inverse morphism be stated seperately? To make myself clear my question is that does the inverse morphism in metric spaces automatically preserve the distance (anologus to the case of algebraic structures that isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism) or is the situation like e.g. toplogical spaces that the continuity should be stated seperately for the invesre function in homeomorphisms?

**EDIT:** In short, the OP asks "If $f:X\to Y$ is a bijective map between metric spaces such that 
$$d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))=d_X(x_1,x_2) \; \; \; \forall x_1,x_2 \in X$$
then is the inverse map $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ also distance preserving i.e. do we have
$$d_X(f^{-1}(y_1),f^{-1}(y_2))=d_Y(y_1,y_2) \; \; \; \forall y_1,y_2 \in Y?$$

Comment: Have you tried a continuous bijection that is not bicontinuous?

Comment: @alephnull I'm not sure what is the relation of trying this to my question

Comment: Isn't a "metric space morphism" just a continuous function from the induced topologies?

Comment: @sanazmat I have added a short summary of the question that (I think!) you are asking. I hope you don't mind and also that it is as you intended!

Comment: @user350031 Sure. I'll be thakful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a bijective distance preserving map between metric spaces.

Let $g:Y\to X$ be the (set theoretic) inverse of $f.$

Take any $y_1,y_2 \in Y.$

Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $y_i=f(x_i)$ for $i=1,2.$

By the distance preserving property of $f,$ we have

$$d_X(x_1,x_2)=d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))$$

which we may rewrite as

$$d_X(g(y_1),g(y_2))=d_Y(y_1,y_2).$$

Since $y_1,y_2$ were arbitrary, we have proved that $g$ is distance preserving.

Hope this clears things up! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, completely crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

A metric space isomorphism is an isomorphism on the induced topologies is a bicontinuous bijection. It is possible to have a continuous bijection (at least in general topologies, not sure about metric spaces) that is not bicontinuous.

Comment: I think that "morphisms of metric spaces" are isometries (i.e. distance preserving maps) not just continuous maps. Hence an isomorphism of metric spaces is an isometry $f:X\to Y$ for which there exists another isometry $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g = \mathrm{id}_Y$ and $g\circ f = \mathrm{id}_X.$

Comment: @user350031 Oh I see. Yeah I agree with you. My answer was bad.

Comment: @sanazmat Yes it does, but not the other way around. Thus the distinction.

Comment: I've also seen morphisms of the category of metric spaces to be non-espanding maps do $d_Y(f(x), f(x')) \le d_X(x,x')$ for $f: X \to Y$. at least we have constant maps (and products e.g. because the projections will be such maps).